# Ubuntu Stuck on Black Screen After Fresh Installation

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, msi

I have an MSI GS63VR. It has an i7-7700HQ CPU, 16 GB of RAM, and an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060.

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS using the steps described on the site. I allocated 40 GBs to Ubuntu. Everything seemed to install correctly.

Once I saw the notification about the installation being successful, the machine said I'd need to restart. I press ok (or whatever the prompt said). It froze there. I left and came back a half hour later and saw it hadn't changed so I manually shut down the machine.

It restarted just fine. Instead of going straight to windows, it brought up the screen where I can choose ubuntu or windows. I chose ubuntu. After that, a black screen came up and nothing happened. It just froze there.

Is there something I can or should do to fix this?

Comment: So I followed the steps there (as far as changing the line to nomodeset) in the grub menu. After I reboot, it gets me to the log in screen (which is farther than I've been, so I think this is a step in the right direction).

After I enter my password, the system freezes. I read through that entire page but I didn't find anything that addresses that possibility. Any chance you might have a tip?

Thank you for the info so far!

Comment: Try booting with a different graphics card or without the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 plugged in.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. But I just did a single change and then everything works --> click install updates and all other packages. install graph card driver as well. Then when you restart, do not remove the medium and press enter to restart. When restarting, remember to chang the order of your BOOT to make the HDD/SSD first. Then I can log into ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow proper procedure, ie first disable windows fast boot and UEFI secure boot?

This should be done before attempting to install Ubuntu (or any other OS/Linux).

Secondly, upon installation and later upgrades, never do a hard-reset. It may seem the PC is doing nothing and is stuck - but allow it plenty of time.

Since it is a fresh install that have turned sour, I'd just as well go ahead and install from scratch. And maybe allow a bit more space for Ubuntu.

Some time ago I set up my ASUS N552VX with Ubuntu 16.04, allowing it 60Gb of the SSD. Which later turned out to be a mistake and increased it to 120Gb. Luckily did not have to do any reinstall, just some partition juggling and resizing.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for responding.

I disabled windows fast boot and uefi secure boot. Is there a page that you recommend with detailed installation instructions?

I used this page: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 And I read on a few different pages that I had to disable fast boot and uefi secure boot. Not sure where I went wrong.

I'll also try allocating more space to the system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Escape from black screen

   When you stuck on black screen, you can use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to select terminal. Then you can type your username and password to login.
2. edit `/etc/default/grub`

   Modify the line of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='pcie_port_pm=off acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"'
   ```

   Then reboot again. You should be able to see login page.
3. Re-install nvidia driver (If step 1 & 2 cannot help)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-390 nvidia-settings
   ```